# Problem with php function to catch error on saving image

Tags: php

I have a method to save an image, which is meant to deal gracefully with an error, setting $imageSrc to a particular image in the event of failure. My method works fine if the image is present, but no error conditions seems to be handled correctly.

```
$imageSrc = save_pic($PIC_URL, $pk);

function save_pic($pic_url, $pk) {
    $imageDir = './';
    if (!strlen($pic_url))
            return "removed.jpg";
    if (!is_dir($imageDir) || !is_writable($imageDir)) {
        return "removed.jpg";
    }
    $image = file_get_contents($pic_url);
    if (empty($image)) {
        return "removed.jpg";
    }
    $r = file_put_contents($imageDir.$pk.".jpg", $image);
    if ($r) {
            return "./$pk.jpg"; 
    } else {
            return "removed.jpg";
    }
}
```

If the image does not exist, I get :

```
Warning: getimagesize(http://127.0.0.1/555.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\get_auction.php on line 144

Array (
 [type] => 2 [message] => getimagesize(http://127.0.0.1/555.jpg)
 function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 [file] => C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\get_auction.php
 [line] => 144
) 1
```

returned.jpg is never returned in any event.

edit: added imageResize code:

```
function imageResize($imageURL, $maxWidth, $maxHeight)

{

global $outputWidth, $outputHeight, $maxWidth, $maxHeight;

$size = getimagesize($imageURL);

if ($size) {

    $imageWidth  = $size[0];

    $imageHeight = $size[1];

    $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;

    $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;

    $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);



    if ($maxRatio > 1) {

        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;

        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;

    } else {

        $outputWidth = $imageWidth;

        $outputHeight = $imageHeight;

    }

} else {

    die(print_r(error_get_last()));

}

}
```

Comment: isn't PHP crazy or what! :) ... "a .Net guy" ;)

Comment: There's code missing here... where is getimagesize message coming from?

Comment: It is not clear at which point you're calling imageResize() from your other code. Please re-organize to provide everything including current error message, if you still can't fix it yourself, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not a code issue, but was caused by file corruption. This was determined while testing on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're writing to the root folder? Because I can't see any problem with your code. `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` don't seem to be failing, so your image is being written somewhere.

Comment: but it doesnt deal with the file not existing in order to get

Comment: so file_get_contents *should* return FALSE but doesn't, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, The problem is not with the folder being writable, but with the image not existing at the url

Answer (score 0):

```
 $image = file_get_contents("http://example.com/test.png");
 list($ver, $retcode, $message) = explode(' ', $http_response_header[0], 3);
 if ($retcode != 200) {
   return "removed.jpg";
 }
```

`$retcode` will contain `HTTP` response code.

Please post this `$retcode` here and what your `strlen($image)` returns, it might help to resolve your problem.

Comment: I put this in my code as you suggest, and only the file_Get_contens error is output, nothing after that.

Comment: Does it ever get after file_get_contents? Put an echo right after file_get_contents and see if it gets there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$imageSrc = save_pic($PIC_URL, $pk);

function save_pic($pic_url, $pk) 
{
    $imageDir = './';

    if (!strlen($pic_url))
    {
        return 'removed.jpg';
    }

    if(!is_dir($imageDir) || !is_writable($imageDir)) 
    {
        return 'removed.jpg';
    }

    if(!file_exists($pic_url))
    {
        return 'removed.jpg';
    }

    if (file_put_contents($imageDir . $pk . '.jpg', file_get_contents($pic_url))) 
    {
            return $imageDir . $pk . '.jpg'; 
    } 
    else 
    {
            return 'removed.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bart, this had the same exact behavior.

Comment: Can you post the code from C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\get_auction.php around line 144?

Because that is what's causing this error:
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\get_auction.php on line 144

Comment: line 144 is just $imageSrc = save_pic($PIC_URL, $pk);

Answer (score 0):

Debug?

Get an IDE that includes a debugger, like Eclipse or Netbeans, rtm for functions to see how the respond, or do bad-old inline debugging to echo the value of code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're not posting your complete code?

The warning message says `getimagesize()`, yet nowhere is `getimagsize()` used in your example. To receive better help I would include the whole method or an updated error message of your current efforts. Please also include the PHP version you're using.

`file_get_contents()` will return false in case of errors and does so on 404 HTTP errors, as demonstrated:

```
mfischer@testing01:~$ php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/i_do_not_exist.jpg"));'

Warning: file_get_contents(http://stackoverflow.com/i_do_not_exist.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
    0.0002      51884   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0002      51952   2. file_get_contents() Command line code:1

bool(false)
mfischer@testing01:~$ php -v
PHP 5.2.6-5 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct  5 2008 13:07:13)
```

Trying out your code it works perfectly fine for me here:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
$PIC_URL="http://stackoverflow.com/i_dont_exist.jpg";
$pk = "test";
$imageSrc = save_pic($PIC_URL, $pk);
var_dump($imageSrc);

function save_pic($pic_url, $pk) {
    $imageDir = './';
    if (!strlen($pic_url))
            return "removed.jpg";
    if (!is_dir($imageDir) || !is_writable($imageDir)) {
        return "removed.jpg";
    }
    $image = file_get_contents($pic_url);
    if (empty($image)) {
        return "removed.jpg";
    }
    $r = file_put_contents($imageDir.$pk.".jpg", $image);
    if ($r) {
            return "./$pk.jpg";
    } else {
            return "removed.jpg";
    }
}
$ php test.php

Warning: file_get_contents(http://stackoverflow.com/i_dont_exist.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in /home/mfischer/tmp/532480/test.php on line 14

Call Stack:
    0.0005      59824   1. {main}() /home/mfischer/tmp/532480/test.php:0
    0.0005      60176   2. save_pic() /home/mfischer/tmp/532480/test.php:4
    0.0006      60444   3. file_get_contents() /home/mfischer/tmp/532480/test.php:14

string(11) "removed.jpg"
```

PHP functions have the bad habit of just spilling out warning messages right in your code, if you don't like this you can silence them with the '@' operate as suggested before or you can alternatively use a HTTP Client library as provided by PEAR_HTTP or Zend_HTTP_Client to have better control of error handling. Rolling your own thing with sockets, fsockopen, etc. would also be possible.

But back to the point: if it's still not working, I think there's some information missing.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the ImageResize function. The problem seems to be with the 404 error however.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be testing for file_get_contents errors? I mean with something like

```
if( false == ($image = file_get_contents($pic_url))){
        return "removed.jpg";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Send HTTP HEAD to given URL
- Check returncode == 200 (file is there) else it's removed
- Check that Content-Type header is image/* (for example image/png) else it's removed
- If server sent Content-Length header, read that to variable
- file_get_contents(URL)
- If server sent that Content-Length see if size matches else it's removed
- Save image
- Try getimagesize(), if it gives errors remove it via unlink() and it's removed else keep it
- Success!

Answer (score 0):

You are having path issues. You should store the full path to the pic in a define.

Make sure this file is sourced from the save_pic function.

```
DEFINE("RemovedPicUrl", "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/path/to/removed/image/removed.jpg")
```

then change all occurances of

```
"Removed.jpg"
```

to

```
RemovedPicUrl
```

And I'll bet you a dollar that fixes your issue.